# Is it possible to create a coupon code in magento that will apply 2 different percentage discount

Tags: magento2, coupon

Is it possible to create a coupon code in Magento (2.3) that will apply 2 different percentage discount depending on the cart content:

- If user have 1 item: X% off the whole cart
- If users have 2 or more item: Y% off the whole cart

I didn't find anything similar in the documentation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this via magento standard functionality. To do this you could create your custom sales rule action (https://i.stack.imgur.com/j19nC.png) with custom fields in sales rule form. There is an example of how to create a custom discount action - https://github.com/Smile-SA/magento2-module-gift-sales-rule